# Wrong/Mixed Language in KDE

Tags: localization, kde-plasma

After KDE upgrade I got a mixed language.
Normaly it has to be german language, but most of KDE was in english after upgrade.

The result of echo $lang was something like : de_C.UTF-8 instead of de_DE.UTF-8

So the Country-Setting seems to be wrong.

In System Settings -> Locale -> Country/Region & Language -> Country, my only choices are:

- System Country ()
- No Country (Default Settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One part of the Problem was, that I used localepurge. This remove some "unneeded Language-Packages".

The easy, but hard to find solution was to remove setlocale.sh and relogin.
This file will be recreatet if you relogin.

You'll find your setlocale.sh in ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with localepurge in Ubuntu 14.04 (fix was released only 7 hours ago). As for now I've run this commands to solve similar problem:

```
sudo apt-get purge localepurge
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kde-runtime-data kdelibs5-data
```

No re-login is necessary!